# Nested Json data won't be decoded using Swift language?

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I'm receiving response data from an API, when I'm trying to decode it by using json decoder, the nested json data won't be decoded because it returns null.

json data as follow:

```
{
    "token": "string",
    "details": {
        "ID": "string",
        "Name": "string",
        "Message": null
    }
}
```

Decoding model is:

```
struct response: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let usrData: userData?
}
struct userData:Codable{
    let ID,Name,Message: String?
}
```

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "Please check internet connection")))
                return
            }
            guard let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(response.self, from:data) else
            {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
            }
            print(loginResponse.userData?.userID as Any) //returns nil
            print(loginResponse.token) //token printed
            guard let token = loginResponse.token else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidCredentials))
                return
           }
            completion(.success(token))
        }.resume()
```

The token from the response will be successfully decoded, but the userData returns null.

Comment: `userDto`, I guess it's `userData`. You don't write that `usrData` needs to be fetched on the key `details` from your JSON. It doesn't match...

Comment: And as a recommendation: Never use `try?`, use a `do`/`try`/`catch`, and name your class/struct names starting with an uppercase, and your variable with a lower case.

Comment: Change ``usrData`` to ``details`` or using ``CodingKeys``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model's property name and decoded json property name must be equal if your are not mapping , so change your struct with :

```
struct response: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let details: userDto?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That certainly can not work, first, in your `response` struct you have a let variable that says `usrData` that can not be identified as `details`. Second you write `usrData: userDto` what is `userDto` you clearly did a mistake or forgot to mention it. However, do it like that for example:

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let details: UserData?
}

struct UserData: Codable {
    let ID,Name,Message: String?
}

let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"test", ofType: "json")
let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!))

if let loginResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
    loginResponse
}
```

The example is not completely correct, because `fileURLWithPath` is deprecated but you should get the idea from it.

I also recommend following some basic roles, like writing `Struct`s with an uppercase letter.